# How can I pass the user claims from the dedicated identity API to internal APIs in ASP.NET core?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identity

The requirement is to not use the Microsoft Identity service/server. I already implemented Jwt authentication in my own identity API. But the internal API will sometimes need to get the already authenticated claims.

One way to do this is to add all authenticated claims to the outgoing HttpClient request headers in the identity API. The issue with this is the claim names must remain simple to comply to the format requirement of http header names. This means I cannot use the `ClaimTypes` names as the claim types.

Another way is to simply pass the original Jwt token from identity API to internal API, the so-called propagation. However, this requires the internal API to have the ability to decrypt and validate the token, which is not supposed to be within its responsibility.

Comment: AFAIK, If we use some Oauth compatible solution like `IdentityServer` or `OpenIdDict`. Everything that need to decrpyt/usage of the access Jwt token would be public on wellknow endpoint. And we just needed to config the internal service to point right to that central Identity Server to get it work. Of course, If we invented our own way to  generate access token manually, then we also need to take care of that wellknow endpoint to make things work

Comment: `which is not supposed to be within its responsibility`, so how about creating an api which   offers the ability of decoding jwt token?

Comment: The problem is that every request to any internal api will need to authorize the claims. I don't want to have an http call to the central authentication service in each such request.

Comment: Hmmm, then how about adding a filter to check if there's a jwt token in the request header and can decode the token, modify the request header, then pass the request to controller?

Comment: This will validate the token twice, as it's already been validated in the authentication service.